# Did Tiger Millionaire's wrestling change after Steven learns to fly and gains strength?

Tags: steven-universe

In *Steven Universe*, the titular character joins with Amethyst to form a tag team wrestling duo that went by the name of "Tiger Millionaire". At this point in the series, he was only slightly stronger than the average human. However later on in the show he begins to master various abilities, such as flight.

Is it ever shown in the series or comics how his newfound abilities affected his wrestling persona?

Answer (score 1):

He doesn't appear to continue his wrestling career after that episode he and Amethyst have one last battle to "the good looking guys" and fake tapout so the other wrestlers (the good looking guys) can win as the champions and they end their career then and there.

So we don't know because he ended his career as Tiger Millionaire then Tiger Philanthropist then again as Tiger Millionaire ended all during one episode.